# Stand alone Solr 8 Authentication

Tags: solr

I have followed followed https://gist.github.com/jstrassburg/9777027 and https://lucidworks.com/post/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/
then added security.json in server/solr path but not working

Comment: The first one is for adding authentication directly in the jetty container, while the latter (i.e. using `security.json`) is within the Solr application. Which one have you actually been setting up? If you're using `security.json`, you should not modify the jetty configuration. And what is the content of your `security.json` file?

Comment: this is resolved after putting security.json into /var/solr/data path